# Searching for 2 consecutive hex values in a char array of a file

Tags: c, arrays, search, pointers, hex

I've read a file into an array of characters using fread. Now I want to search that array for two consecutive hex values, namely FF followed by D9 (its a jpeg marker signifying end of file). Here is the code I use to do that:

```
char* searchBuffer(char* b) {
    char* p1 = b;
    char* p2 = ++b;
    int count = 0;

    while (*p1 != (unsigned char)0xFF && *p2 != (unsigned char)0xD9) {
        p1++;
        p2++;
        count++;
    }

    count = count;
    return p1;
}
```

Now I know this code works if I search for hex values that don't include 0xFF (eg 4E followed by 46), but every time I try searching for 0xFF it fails. When I don't cast the hex values to unsigned char the program doesn't enter the while loop, when I do the program goes through all the chars in the array and doesn't stop until I get an out of bounds error. I'm stumped, please help.

Ignore count, its just a variable that helps me debug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm actually not convinced that your conditional is correct. Shouldn't it be `!(*p1 == (unsigned char)0xFF && *p2 == (unsigned char)0xD9)` instead? (Putting aside, for the moment, your problems with `unsigned char` and `unsigned int`) As currently written, it seems that your loop will end whenever it encounters 0xFF *or* 0xD9.

Comment: Why don't you use [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/)?

Comment: Change `&&` to `||` and read Oli's answer.

Comment: @Angel: Because a JPEG file is not a C string.

Comment: Also note that your code has a major design bug handling malformed data. It does not take the length of the buffer as an argument, so it will happily run past the end of the buffer if the terminating bytes are not found, resulting in UB. You can fix this by passing and testing the length, or by always appending terminating bytes to the buffer after reading it from the file.

Comment: @R.., Chris said he's read the file into an array of characters, so I suppose it's a C string now. `strstr()` would do the trick exactly like his current function.

Comment: @Angel: `strstr()` would have problems if the data could contain zero bytes.  I assume that's the case and is why string functions aren't being considered.

Comment: @Angel: A "C string" is not an array of characters. It's an array of characters up to and including the first 0 byte, and nothing past that. This is a big difference.

Comment: @R.. Could you explain why the && wouldn't work? Thanks, OP

Comment: You have a mismatch for the end marker if *either* byte mismatches, not only if they both mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling foul of *integer promotions*.  Both operands for `!=` (and similar) are promoted to `int`.  And if at least one of them is `unsigned`, then both of them are treated as `unsigned` (actually that isn't 100% accurate, but for this particular situation, it should suffice).  So this:

```
*p1 != (unsigned char)0xFF
```

is equivalent to:

```
(unsigned int)*p1 != (unsigned int)(unsigned char)0xFF
```

On your platform, `char` is evidently `signed`, in which case it can never take on the value of `(unsigned int)0xFF`.

So try casting `*p1` as follows:

```
(unsigned char)*p1 != 0xFF
```

Alternatively, you could have the function take `unsigned char` arguments instead of `char`, and avoid all the casting.

*[Note that on top of all of this, your loop logic is incorrect, as pointed out in various comments.]*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `memchr()` to find potential matches?

Also, make sure you're dealing with promotions of potentially signed types (`char` may or may not be signed).  Note that while `0xff` and `0xd9` have the high bit set when looked at as 8-bit values, they are non-negative integer constants, so there is no 'sign extension' that occurs for them:

```
char* searchBuffer(char* b) {
    unsigned char* p1 = (unsigned char*) b;
    int count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        /* find the next 0xff char */
        /* note - this highlights that we really should know the size   */
        /* of the buffer we're searching, in case we don't find a match */
        /* at the moment we're making it up to be some large number     */
        p1 = memchr(p1, 0xff, UINT_MAX);
        if (p1 && (*(p1 + 1) == 0xd9)) {
            /* found the 0xff 0xd9 sequence */
            break;
        }

        p1 += 1;
    }

    return (char *) p1;
}
```

Also, note that you really should be passing in some notion of the size of the buffer being searched, in case the target isn't found.

Here's a version that takes a buffer size paramter:

```
char* searchBuffer(char* b, size_t siz) {
    unsigned char* p1 = (unsigned char*) b;
    unsigned char* end = p1 + siz;

    for (;;) {
        /* find the next 0xff char */
        p1 = memchr(p1, 0xff, end - p1);
        if (!p1) {
            /* sequnce not found, return NULL */
            break;
        }


        if (((p1 + 1) != end) && (*(p1 + 1) == 0xd9)) {
            /* found the 0xff 0xd9 sequence */
            break;
        }

        p1 += 1;
    }

    return (char *) p1;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a major bug if `memchr` ever returns 0 (it subsequently begins searching from `(unsigned char *)0+1`). Of course OP's code was also broken (by design) in this case too.

Comment: Also, while in practice it should work, I think passing `UINT_MAX` to `memchr` as "unknown size" like this actually results in UB. The buffer argument to `memchr` must actually be an object of the specified size, per the standard.

Comment: @R.: that's noted in the comments about the unknown buffer size.  I'll post a version that takes a size parameter.

Comment: Indeed, what threw me off was that you were checking that the return value was non-null in one place, but then later (outside that conditional) assuming it had been non-null.

Answer (score 1):

4E will promote itself to a positive integer but `*p1` will be negative with FF, and then will be promoted to a very large unsigned value that will be far greater than FF.

You need to make `p1` *unsigned.*

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code a lot shorter as:

```
char* searchBuffer(const char* b) {
    while (*b != '\xff' || *(b+1) != '\xd9') b++;
    return b;
}
```

Also note the function will cause a segmentation fault (or worse, return invalid results) if b does not, in fact, contain the bytes FFD9.

Answer (score 1):

use void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t haystacklen, const void *needle, size_t needlelen);

which is available in string.h and easy to use.

```
char* searchBuffer(char* b, int len) 
{
    unsigned char needle[2] = {0xFF, 0XD9};
    char * c;
    c = memmem(b, len, needle, sizeof(needle));
    return c;
}
```